# R applying to a line

Tags: r, apply

I have a data frame that contains multiple rows and multiple columns.

I have a character vector that contains the names of some of the columns in the data frame. The number of columns can vary.

For each line, for each of these columns, I have to identify if one of them is not NA. (basically `any(!is.na(df[namecolumns]))` for each line), to then do a subset for the ones that are `TRUE`.

Actually, `any(!is.na(df[1,][namescolumns]))` works well, but it's only for the first line.

I could easily do a for loop, which is my first reflex as a programmer and because it works for the first line, but I'm sure it's not the `R` way and that there is a way to do this with an `"apply"` (`lapply`, `mapply`, `sapply`, `tapply` or other), but I can't figure out which one and how.

Thank you.

Comment: I think we need more information about what namecolumns looks like, at least. Data examples are always helpful.

Comment: Example for the format: `namescolumns <- names(df)[1:3]`, but it can be any number of columns (not necessarily 1:3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using `apply` over the first dimension (rows):

```
apply(df, 1 function(x) any(!is.na(x[namescolumns])))
```

The results will come back transposed, and so, you might want to wrap the whole statement inside of `t(.)`

Comment: Works great even with subset(df, t(apply(df, 1, function(x) any(!is.na(x[namescolumns]))))). Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of `lapply` and `Reduce`

```
has.na.in.cols <- Reduce(`&`, lapply(colnames, function (name) !is.na(df[name])))
```

to get a vector of whether or not there are `NA` values in any of the columns in `colnames`, which can in turn be used to subset the data.

```
df[has.any.na,]
```

For example. Given:

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3,4,NA,6,7),
                 b = c(2,4,6,8,10,12,14),
                 c = c("one","two","three","four","five","six","seven"),
                 d = c("a",NA,"c","d","e","f","g")
                 )
colnames <- c("a","d")
```

You can get:

```
> df[Reduce(`&`, lapply(colnames, function (name) !is.na(df[name]))),]
  a b      c d
1 1 2    one a
3 3 6  three c
4 4 8   four d
6 6 12   six f
7 7 14 seven g
```